# Стилизация пагинатора

Tags: html, css

подскажите, как сделать такую же рамку(для страниц 1,2,3,4), чтобы был единый `border`, но при этом при наведении на отдельную ссылку она подсвечивала только свои границы. решил убрать `border-right` для всех, кроме последнего, а так же сделать `margin -1px` чтобы визуально выглядело как единое целое, но возникла проблема, если навести на ссылку, которая рядом с активной ссылкой, то получается двойной `border`. как от этого избавиться? или можно как-то в целом по другому сделать?

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.main__paginator li {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.main__paginator a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid 1px #BDBDBD;
  /* border-radius: 5px; */
  color: #3205F3;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  margin: 0 -1px;
}

.paginator__page-number a {
  border-right:0;
}

.paginator__page-number {
  display: flex;
  border-right:0;
}


.main__paginator .paginator__page-number li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}


.main__paginator .paginator__left {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.main__paginator .paginator__right {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.main__paginator .paginator__right a,
.main__paginator .paginator__left a {
  width: 105px;
}

.main__paginator .active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 184, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.main__paginator .active a {
  border: 1px solid #3205F3;
  border-color: #3205F3;
}

.main__paginator a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(20, 0, 213, 0.05);
  border: solid 1px #3205F3;
}
```

```html
  <ul class="main__paginator">
        <li class="paginator__left"><a href="#">Left</a></li>
        <div class="paginator__page-number">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">4</a></li>
        </div>
        <li class="paginator__right"><a href="#">Right</a></li>
      </ul>
```

[image: пример как нужно сделать]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с псевдоэлементом

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}
.list__item:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.list__item--active .list__link::before,
.list__link:hover::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  content: "";
}
.list__item:first-child .list__link::before {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.list__item:last-child .list__link::before {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.list__link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list__link">1</a></li>
    <li class="list__item  list__item--active"><a href="#" class="list__link">2</a></li>
    <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list__link">3</a></li>
    <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list__link">4</a></li>
    <li class="list__item"><a href="#" class="list__link">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, только вы видимо забыли указать, чтобы ховер эффект располагался на `top: -1px`, потому что иначе границы выглядят некрасиво
`.list__item--active .list__link::before,
.list__link:hover::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 1px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  content: "";
}`

Comment: @Bender если поднять на `1px`, то нужно сделать высоту `before` равную `100%`. Исправил пример.